# Relative advantages of nnet, neuralnet, caret and RSNNS packages

Tags: neural-networks

What are the relative advantages and disadvantages of different packages available for neural networks: nnet, neuralnet, caret and RSNNS? Which is best in terms of simplicity? Which is best for general purpose use? And which is the one for advanced networks? Also where do Bayesian networks stand in terms of these aspects?

Answer (score 0):

Section 7.1 from Bergmeir & Benítez Sánchez (2012) is the reference for RSNNS and provides a short overview on neuralnet and nnet. Package nnet is the simplest one and restricted to a single layer; RSNNS and neuralnet have more options.

Bergmeir, C. N., & Benítez Sánchez, J. M. (2012). Neural networks in R using the Stuttgart neural network simulator: RSNNS. American Statistical Association. 
https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v046i07/v46i07.pdf